# When and how to separate Control and Datapaths for hardware designs?

Tags: fpga, verilog, state-machines

Must we always separate control and datapath during hardware programming? Are there any advantages? If yes then what is the basic methodology followed for this strategy? I am trying to interface an SDHC card with FPGA and am confused in implementing the protocol using separate data and control paths.

Comment: It all depends on your application...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should *always* split these two parts in your designs.
(Btw. I wouldn't speak of those two if we are talking about simple modules.)

Splitting datapath and control has these advantages:

- better maintainability

  - data path is easier to understand, because its a flow / directed graph
  - FSMs are easier to understand because they are not overfilled with data
- "faster" development

  - delegate development to multiple developers
  - datapath modules might get reused in the same or in other projects.
    If both are entwined, a datapath module will not be universal and disallows code/module reuse
- better testability

  - test datapath modules independently of control
  - test control (mainly one or more FSMs) independently
  - use dummy architectures in the datapath while testing the hosting module
    computation

Splitting datapath and control also implies to split of parts of the control in subcontrol units like sub-FSMs, counters, ...

Comment: Always is severely over stating the case, there can be perfectly valid reasons for combining the two. Consider something like some Xilinx IP block, in the 7 series these tend to have AXI IO which can include user data that is just passed thru (With the correct latency to match the latency of the core), this can be a HUGE win as using it means not having to reconsider pipeline latencies when you reconfigure the core. It does make separating control and data harder however, but sometimes in a largely dataflow driven application, that is worth doing.

Comment: In your example, the control information is actually data that is delayed. The IP core does interpret such data it's just delayed.

Comment: My point is that you usually want control transitions to respect the data delays and that writing them together so you can use the delay chains built into the IP cores (and thus automatically match the latencies) can be a huge win. I get twitchy when works like **Always** are used when describing design approaches because there are usually exceptions and being absolute about such things removes one set of sometimes useful options.

Comment: Does this splitting also affect the hardware implementation or synthesis?

Comment: Not really, it's a coding and design style.